# How to install cassandra on Windows 10?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to get and install `Cassandra` on Windows 10(x64). Not able to download any Datastax enterprise edition for Windows. Can anyone suggest the steps to do download ,install it and configure on Windows 10.

Comment: Step 1 - Install Linux.

Comment: on widows use Virtual Machines there u can search Bitnami Cassandra Stack for Virtual Machines

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following

1. Install virtual Machine
2. Download Latest Centos and Install it on Virtual Machine
3. Install Cygwin on windows ( you can use different software as well ) to access Cassandra on Windows
4. Follow Bitnami Steps on how to install Dockers and download Cassandra Image on your Virtual Machine

(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-centos-7)

- you may choose other Cassandra Image aswell but i personally prefer Bitnami

Answer (score 0):

To be able to install Cassandra on Windows, first you need to:

1. Download and Install Java 8 and set environment variables.
2. Download and install Python 2.7 and set environment variables.

Then Visit the official Apache Cassandra Download page and select the version you would prefer to download and Set Up Apache Cassandra

Here's a link to full explanation https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-windows